# Remove Square Brackets - Json Data - CakePHp RESTful

Tags: json, rest, cakephp, ember.js

I am using CakePHP to create a RESTful api that is connected to via EmberJS from the front end.

The following code within CakePHP is generating the JSON I need but it is putting in square brackets that EmberJS doesn't like. How do I go about getting the data without the square brackets?

CakePHP view

```
public function view($id = null) {

    if($id == NULL)
    {
        $id = $this->request->params['id'];
    }

    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $options = array('conditions' => array('Content.' . $this->Content->primaryKey => $id));
    $content = $this->Content->find('first', $options);
    $content = Set::extract('/Content/.', $content);

    $this->set('content', $content);

    $this->set('_serialize', $content);

    ;

}
```

view.ctp

```
echo json_encode(compact('content'));
```

It is returning this:

```
{
    "content":
    [{
     "id":"1",
     "name":"Home",
     "extended":"This is the homepage.",
     "created":"2013-08-05 23:40:55",
     "modified":"2013-08-05 23:40:55"
    }]
}
```

I need this:

```
{
    "content":
    {
     "id":"1",
     "name":"Home",
     "extended":"This is the homepage.",
     "created":"2013-08-05 23:40:55",
     "modified":"2013-08-05 23:40:55"
    }
}
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are arrays in Javascript/JSON.  You apparently need an object (I've never used EmberJs).  So:

```
json_encode(compact('content'),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked to remove the square brackets. I am now however getting this: {"content":{"0":{"id":"1","name":"Home","extended":"This is the homepage.","created":"2013-08-05 23:40:55","modified":"2013-08-05 23:40:55"}}}  NOTE the "0" record under content. How do I get rid of this? Thanks

Comment: I ended up using this $this->set('content', $content[0]); and it works. Thanks again.